# WSL: sudo apt-get update fails with "Cannot initiate..." and "Failed to fetch..." errors

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt

I am unable to run the sudo apt-get update on my WSL on windows 10, here is the dump:

```
gyuun@LAPTOP-PR:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

gyuun@LAPTOP-PR:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Any chance that Windows is connected via a VPN?  Also, as noted in the Ask Ubuntu question, are there any other networking issues going on in WSL?  Can you `ping superuser.com`?

Comment: Yes, ping works fine. There is no VPN. This is the first time I am using WSL. I only installed in today you see.

Comment: I just tried ping command with security.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com, both work with ping but the apt-get update still does not work, I am lost.

Comment: For me it was the corporate proxy, this was my solution: sudo http_proxy=http://<ip>:<port>  https_proxy=http://<ip>:<port> apt-get update

Comment: corporate proxies have killed me